# ESP8266 not starting with marcelstoer nodemcu docker built bin file

Tags: docker, nodemcu

I have followed the instructions of of Marcel Stor as detailed  https://hub.docker.com/r/marcelstoer/nodemcu-build/ and created a nodemcu bin file that I flash to my ESP8266 in a similar way than with the frigtanic cloud build service I have used up to now.

The bin file created is `nodemcu_float_dev_20181102-1149.bin`

To build this I forked the a copy of the `dev` branch of the `nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware`to my GitHub account and cloned a copy using GitHub Desktop to a local repository. In `user_modules.h` I defined a few modules and in `user_config.h` tried a number of options using `#define FLASH_4M` and `#define FLASH_AUTOSIZE`.

I fully erase the ESP8266 before flashing. After flashing I do not get the normal formatting message followed by the startup information indicating the NodeMCU version with modules included in the build.

I only get the following followed by garbage:

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:1, boot mode:(3,6)
load 0x40100000, len 30104, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0xa9
load 0x3ffe8000, len 2236, room 0
tail 12
chksum 0x48
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load 0x3ffe88bc, len 8, room 12
tail 8
chksum 0x56
csum 0x56
```

I use the latest Espressif ESP8266 download tool and flash the bin file to `0x00000` and have also tried flashing the `0x00000.bin` and `0x10000.bin` files to the correct adresses. The tool autodetects the flash size as 32Mbit (4MB).

Any help to solve this will be appreciated.

Comment: Can the issue be reproduced in qemu? (I ask because an in-emulator reproducer would significantly increase the set of people able to reproduce the issue, and/or test answers; a [mcve] that requires waiting for a microcontroller to ship from China has a pretty high bar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed.

I forked the wrong nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware version from GitHub. Ended up with something from 2016. I cloned and got the correct version from the master branch. Now I only have to figure out how to get the dev branch from GitHub.

Comment: We have instructions in our contributor guidelines: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#working-with-git-and-github. Does that help?